# Wavelets on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: wavelets

I want to study Wavelet theory on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and I can't find any book on this topic. Can you recommend me any good book that considers that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [site](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~adhemar.bultheel/WWW/WAVE/references.html) helps you find your desired book.

Comment: Thank you very much for this link. I think it will help.